# jquery - group li elements and create a togglable hide-show ul

Tags: jquery, html-lists, toggle

I have a `<ul>` with a bunch of `<li>` on some of my pages and I'm trying to figure out how to group them using jquery and create a clickable show-hide UL so my page doesn't have a huge scroll.

My UL looks like this

```
<ul class="my-ul">
<li class="Colour green small">text</li>
<li class="Colour green large">text</li>
<li class="Colour green medium">text</li>
<li class="Colour red small">text</li>
<li class="Colour red large">text</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to group them by the category (Colour) and attribute (green) so I woul have something like this in my page:

```
- Colour
```

and on click, list all its childs

```
- Colour
  - green
```

on clicking green, list all green's childs

```
- Colour 
  - green
    - small
    - large
    - medium
```

Is this possible via jquery?

I can manipulate in my PHP script how the `<ul>` and `<li>` are constructed.

Comment: Each `<li>` can contain another `<ul>` listing a sub-group. Then use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) to show and hide the sublists.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make the sub choices ul's in the lis....something like this:

```js
$("li").on("click",function(event){
  $(this).find("> ul").toggle();
  event.stopPropagation(); //you don't want to affect the clicked element's parent...
})
```

```css
.green {
  color:green;
}
.red {
  color:red;
}
.small {
  font-size:small;
}
.large {
  font-size:large;
}
ul {
    list-style:none;
}
li {
    cursor:pointer;
}
ul ul {
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="my-ul">
  <li class="Colour">
    Colour
    <ul>
        <li class="green">
          green
          <ul>
            <li class="small">small green</li>
            <li class="large">large green</li>
            <li class="medium">medium green</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="red">
          red
          <ul>
            <li class="small">small red</li>
            <li class="large">large red</li>
            <li class="medium">medium red</li>
          </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it would probably be easier to refactor the php code, than to write js that does this...

Comment: It works, but I just found out that my PHP script spits the <li> via a "for each" so my <li> are not grouped.

I need to also group them, either by jquery or directly in my foreach

`<ul>
    <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
    <li class="<?php echo $attribute; ?>">
    <?php echo $attribute; ?>
    <ul>
        <li class="<?php echo $colour; ?>">
          <?php echo $colour; ?>
          <ul>
            <li class="<?php echo $size; ?>"><?php echo $size; ?></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>`

Answer (score 0):

I think this exapmle usefull for you. Just onClick ul-red or ul-green li's and open sub-ul(sub-green,sub-red).

```
<ul class="my-ul">
<li class="ul-green">Green</li>
<ul class="sub-green">
    <li class="small">text</li>
    <li class="large">text</li>
    <li class="medium">text</li>
</ul>
<li class="ul-red">Red</li>
<ul class="sub-red">
    <li class="small">text</li>
    <li class="large">text</li>
</ul>
</ul>
```